# If a random variable $X$ is such that $P(X=0)<1,$ then there is an $\varepsilon>0$ with $P(\vert X\vert>\varepsilon)>0$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, solution-verification

> $\textbf{The Problem:}$ Show that if a random variable $X$ is such that $P(X=0)<1,$ then there is an $\varepsilon>0$ with $P(\vert X\vert>\varepsilon)>0.$

$\textbf{My Proof:}$ Since $P(X=0)<1,$ we have that $0<P(\{X=0\}^\complement)=P(\vert X\vert>0)\leq1$. Now suppose that no such  $\varepsilon>0$ exists. Then for all $n\in\mathbb N$ we have $P\left(\vert X\vert>\frac{1}{n}\right)=0$. Now the sequence $\left(\left\{\vert X\vert>\frac{1}{n}\right\}\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is nested with $\left\{\vert X\vert>\frac{1}{n}\right\}\nearrow\{\vert X\vert>0\}.$ To see this, note that for $n\in\mathbb N$ we have that if $\vert X(\omega)\vert>\frac{1}{n}$, then $\vert  X(\omega)\vert>\frac{1}{n+1}$, so $\left\{\vert X\vert>\frac{1}{n}\right\}\subseteq\left\{\vert X\vert>\frac{1}{n+1}\right\}$. Now let $\omega\in\bigcup_n\left\{\vert X\vert>\frac{1}{n}\right\}.$ Then there is $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $\vert X(\omega)\vert>\frac{1}{n}$, and hence $\vert X(\omega)\vert>0$. Thus, $\bigcup_n\left\{\vert X\vert>\frac{1}{n}\right\}\subseteq\{\vert X\vert>0\}.$ For the reverse inclusion let $\omega\in\{\vert X\vert>0\}.$ Then by the Archimedean property there exists $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $\vert X(\omega)\vert>\frac{1}{n}$, so $\omega\in\bigcup_n\left\{\vert X\vert>\frac{1}{n}\right\}.$ Hence, $\bigcup_n\left\{\vert X\vert>\frac{1}{n}\right\}=\{\vert X\vert>0\}.$
Thus, the continuity of the probability measure implies that
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}P\left(\left\{\vert X\vert>\frac{1}{n}\right\}\right)=P(\vert X\vert>0)=0,$$
which is a contradiction. The result follows.

---

Do you agree with the proof above? If not, it would be much appreciated if anyone could please point out where the proof goes wrong.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: the $\leq 1$ in the first line should be a $> 0$. Otherwise no complaints. Your argument boils down to: the probability space is the countable disjoint union of the sets $1/(n+1) \leq abs(X) < 1/n$ and $X = 0$, so if the measure of this last set isn't 1 then the measure of one of the former ones has to be greater than zero. In this language I don't think you need to appeal to continuity from above/below, but nothing wrong with doing so either.

Comment: @hunter that is a way more elegant solution, thank you